# .NET 5 read & write CookieContainer from/to file

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I've migrated .NET Core 3.1 project to .NET 5 and I am facing problem with write and read cookies from file, because is deprecated.

What is correct way to solve the problem? Thank you

```
public static CookieContainer ReadCookiesFromDisk(string path)
    {
        if (File.Exists(path) == false)
        {
            return new CookieContainer();
        }

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            return (CookieContainer)formatter.Deserialize(stream);
        }
    }

    public static void WriteCookiesToDisk(string path, CookieContainer cookieContainer)
    {
        if (cookieContainer == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        using (Stream stream = File.Create(path))
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(stream, cookieContainer);
        }
    }
```

Warning is "BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream)' is obsolete: 'BinaryFormatter serialization is obsolete and should not be used. See https://aka.ms/binaryformatter for more information."

Error is "BinaryFormatter serialization and deserialization are disabled within this application".

My plan is refactor the code, not allowed deprecated code. Thank you very much

Comment: Did you go to that URL? There's a [Preferred Alternatives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide#preferred-alternatives) section...

Comment: Could you help me with usage? I don't know how to implement it. Thank you

Comment: Extract all Cookies as CookieCollection and serialize it e.g. to JSON.

Comment: ok, thank you. I get it :-)